# AngularJS TypeError: is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting this error, I tried to put roomService.isExist inside a function and call it but same error occurs

[image: roomService.isExist is not a function]

This is what is inside my controller:

```js
import { roomService } from 'roomService';
angular.module('roomCreation', ['api'])
  .controller('RoomController', ($scope, $element, $timeout, Api) => {
    const nameInput = $element[0].querySelector('input');
    $scope.room = Api.getRoom();
    $scope.$watch('elements[0].name', () => {
      roomService.isExist($scope.room.name, $scope.room.domainId).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      })
      $scope.setValid((!!$scope.elements[0].name));

    });
    $timeout(() => {
      domUtils.putCursorAtEnd(nameInput);
    });
  });
```

```html
<div class="Room-nameEditor" ng-controller ="RoomController">
  <form name="linkForm">
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" name="template" ng-model="elements[0].name" id="in" clearable/>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you write the `roomService` module yourself or did you install it from npm? Make sure you're importing it correctly... if you wrote it yourself you may have mean `import roomService from "./roomService";`. If you were using the npm module, I couldn't find any documentation for it and it seems to have 2 downloads this month. Do you know what the `roomService` file looks like?

Comment: In fact that's the problem, `roomService` I wrote it myself and I didn't import it correctly.
I should have call it from the controller like that `.controller('RoomController', ($scope, $element, $timeout, Api, RoomService)` and not using import. thank you

Comment: Great. Happy coding!